# Angular PrimeNG: How to style the p-dialog Close icon?

Tags: primeng, angular10

I would like to style the p-dialog's Close Icon. The default 'x' button is in grey color and I would like to change it to white color with font-size increased. I found that we could use .p-dialog-titlebar-close but haven't been successful. I used it in the following way-

```
::ng-deep .p-dialog .p-dialog-titlebar-close {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Please let me know how can I change the 'X' to show in white color. ( Since it currently is barely visible). Greatly appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Attaching the screenshot for detailed explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the following and it works as expected:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-dialog-header-close-icon {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

[image: Example Custom Close Button]